# cypress + lerna: ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, webpack, cypress, lerna

I currently started working with cypress. In a test I want to import code from another module but it's saying `ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`.

I've added the preprocessor like it's described [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor).

[Here](https://github.com/vince1995/cypress-not-working) is a repo that's not working. Cypress is in module `a` and importing a function from module `b`.

Comment: The preprocessor dosn't appear to be installed `npm install --save-dev @cypress/webpack-preprocessor` only its peer dependencies. Appart from that you may need to set `parserOptions.sourceType` to `module` in the babel config.

Comment: Seems like installing the preprocessor was the solution. The babel config is not required. Thanks.

Comment: Will post it as an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually install the preprocessor in your project, not just its peer dependencies: `npm install --save-dev @cypress/webpack-preprocessor`